# Sonatype nexus3 server Manually remove items

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I'm using nexus sonatype-work nexus3. Still it didn't have a cleaning process. So, it has filled. Is there any commands that I can use to find unused images and data? And, how can delete files manually? [image: folder structure]

Comment: Have you looked here?  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Keeping+Disk+Usage+Low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not delete any of the files manually otherwise it lead to issues with retrieving data from your repositories. You should set up some cleanup policies that will maintain the disk space for you - you can learn more about from these resources:

- [Cleanup policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/repository-management/cleanup-policies)
- [Keeping disk usage low](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/planning-your-implementation/keeping-disk-usage-low)
- [Storage management](https://guides.sonatype.com/repo3/technical-guides/storage-primer-nxrm3/)